# How to filter results for specific languages within a ruby RDF.rb gem DBPedia query

Tags: ruby, rdf, dbpedia

I'm stuck with a problem reducing the delivered result set of a DBPedia query I did with the RDF gem. It all works fine with "non-language specific" results but when I try to reduce the delivered literals for the "abstract" relation I'm struggling with limiting the results for certain languages.

The code is as follows:

```
require 'linkeddata'

graph = RDF::Graph.new

graph.load('http://dbpedia.org/resource/NBC')

query_abstract = RDF::Query.new({ 
  :wiki_abstract => {
    RDF::URI('http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract') => :abstract,
  } 
})

results_abstract = query_abstract.execute(graph)

results_abstract.each do |result|
  puts "#{result.wiki_abstract} - Abstract: #{result.abstract}"
end
```

I tried the same with a SPARQL query and I was able to filter the output for @en language without a problem. But when I try to find a solution for this using the RDF gem I failed and couldn't find a helpful hint in the RDF documentation. Does anybody have an idea how to add filters to the above query for languages?

Comment: After a little bit of additional research I found out that the problem is not the filter itself. The filter could be applied by using something like query_abstract.filter { |solution| solution.abstract.language == :es }. The problem is that the query does not contain all the required language information for each entry. Any idea how to load a graph with the complete DBPedia information on languages?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to select results that have the language you need, something like the following:

```
results_abstract.to_a.select {|a| a.abstract.language == :en}.each do |result|
  puts "#{result.wiki_abstract} - Abstract: #{result.abstract}"
end
```

In this case, you won't find any, as it looks like the languages returned are :ru, :ja, :de, :it and nil (plain literal). You could look for plain literals using the following:

```
results_abstract.to_a.select {|a| !a.abstract.has_language?}
```